# Key events are not raised when escape key is pressed on a focused element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to know when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed on an input element. On Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key removes the focus, but JavaScript cannot catch the `keyup`, `keydown`, or `keypress` events.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gstvj9uq/

```js
$("input").keydown(function() {
  alert('keydown');
});

$("input").keyup(function() {
  alert('keyup');
});

$("input").keypress(function() {
  alert('keypress');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Can anyone give a solution to catch Escape key down/up/press event on an input? IE 10 can catch the event, however.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, and here's how to catch it -> https://jsfiddle.net/gstvj9uq/5/

Comment: @adeneo Did you first click the input, then hit esc key? Are you using Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome, and I focused the input and hit escape, and it works just fine ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Had the same problem, turned out to be the vimium extention. Without that, focus is not lost on pressing escape.

Note that the keypress event is never fired for escape, only keydown and keyup

Comment: amazing.I just found vimium had a trick for this condition: https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks#using-the-escape-key-in-inputs.

Comment: The second paragraf of this answer makes all the difference

Comment: Your "Note that the keypress event is never fired for escape, only keydown and keyup" is important enough to be an answer on it's own. Thanks for this addition!

Comment: This might be an issue with just my app (React/Material UI), but I was only able to catch Escape using `keyup`, it wouldn't fire for `keydown`. Tried different browsers/OS's, no extensions installed, only fix was to switch event types.

Comment: @captainGeech Same for my React/MUI app.