# Keyup works while keypress doesn't Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, keypress, keyup

I'm kinda re-learning JS and try to make modal windows in vanilla JS. So, my task is to make Escape button work and close modal on hitting it. I found out that when I put 'keypress' event on document, it fails to work, while 'keyup' works okay. I couldn't find exact info on why it is so. I used to use e.KeyCode but found out it is deprecated. So I mainly have 2 questions I couldn't find direct answers to:

1. why keycode doesn't work?
2. what is the best way to handle keyboard events in 2021?

Here is the code. Console.log doesn't work. If I change keypress to keyup, everything works.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  console.log('Event fired');
  if (e.key === "Escape" && !modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    closeModal();
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Vadim

Comment: One of the things we look for in a question about something not working is the code that produces the "not working" state. Please provide that code. You can use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) (icon looks like <> in the editor toolbar) to do so.

Comment: @vdmclcv Does the keypress event not fire at all?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Yes, seems like it

Comment: @biberman I have updated my post to provide the code and some additional explanations.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Like you said "keyCode" is deprecated but it still works (see example below).
2. The best way in your case would be to use keyup and e.key.

Your code works as expected (with any other key), but the keypress event is never fired for *Escape*. So you can only use keydown and keyup.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log('keypress fired; ', e.key);
})
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log('keyup fired; ', e.key);
  if(e.keyCode == '27') alert('Escape');
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Do you mean that keypress event doesn't work for Esc key and it is how it is meant to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352918/key-events-are-not-raised-when-escape-key-is-pressed-on-a-focused-element). Is there a specific reason why you want to use "keypress" instead of "keyup"?

Comment: No, there is no specific reason for that. I just wondered why keypress does not work and keyup does. Thought maybe that keypress is deprecated or somewhat and couldn't find info on that, hence the question. Thank you for reference, @biberman